# How to push docker image to Nexus repository through Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, nexus

I have a Jenkinsfile pipeline creating 3 docker images/containers as below:

```
stage('Build images')
{
    echo "workspace directory is ${workspace}"
    dir ("$workspace/build/virtuoso")
    {
      sh 'docker build -t virtuoso -f $WORKSPACE/build/virtuoso/Dockerfile .'
    }
    dir ("$workspace/build/wildfly")
    {
      sh 'docker build -t wildfly -f $WORKSPACE/build/wildfly/Dockerfile .'
    }
    dir ("$workspace/build/postgres")
    {
      sh 'docker build -t postgres -f $WORKSPACE/build/postgres/Dockerfile .'
    }
}
```

I need to push these 3 images to Nexus repository manager. Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is:

```
stage('Push Docker Images to Nexus Registry'){
sh 'docker login -u user -p password NexusDockerRegistryUrl'
sh 'docker push NexusDockerRegistryUrl/Imagename}'
sh 'docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference="NexusDockerRegistryUrl/ImageName*" -q)'
sh 'docker logout NexusDockerRegistryUrl'
}
```

The above stage in Jenkins pipeline would push the docekr image to nexus docker registry and remove existing image.

Thanks